# How many simultaneous multi-touch points are supported by the new iPhone 6 and 6 Plus?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, multi-touch

I have an app on the market and I want to update it for the new phones. The old iPhones only supported 5 simultaneous touches where as the iPad supported 10. I was wondering if the new phones now support 10 as well. I searched Google for documentation but I couldn't find specific data.

Answer (score 1):

it's limited by 5 in all iPhones to date.

Comment: Could you add a reference for that?!